# django admin formfield for manytomany not working

Tags: python, django

I was reading this

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_manytomany

and i am trying to query the dtabase with `like field` but i get error

> FieldError: Join on field 'car' not permitted. Did you
>   misspell 'like' for the lookup type?

The code i am uisng is

```
def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "cars":
            kwargs["queryset"] = models.Cars.objects.filter(car_like="ford")
        return super(MyAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code as posted wouldn't throw this error. It can only confuse a join if you used double underscores `car__like`. [You should check out the django query reference for exact details.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/)

Anyways, [perhaps you are looking for `__icontains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#std%3afieldlookup-contains) which generates a LIKE statement?

```
Foo.objects.filter(some_field__icontains='ford')
```